# failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000. connection refused

Tags: docker-compose, sonarqube-scan, concourse

I have concourse , sonarqube server running inside containers and when i am trying to connect to sonarqube server using concourse, it is showing me error i.e SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough information to answer the question.

May be... 
If Concourse CI and SonarQube are in different containers, you have to specify http://container-name-with-sonar-qube:9000 in CI settings.

Comment: i have a docker-compose file under which i have 3 containers , one for concourse, second for sonarqube and third for postgres.
And then i created a pipeline in which i have node image from the docker and then pulled the repo from git and using npm install sonarqube i am trying to scan the code.
But while doing the same i am coming across this error

Comment: @Devanshu, can you post your docker-compose.yml ?